# use more than 1 input inference in Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, inference, virtuoso

I have one `input inference` in Virtuoso Open Source, that was defined from [goodrelations](http://www.heppnetz.de/projects/goodrelations/) site --

```
rdfs_rule_set('http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1', 'http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1');
```

-- that I used in query using --

```
define input:inference <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1> .
```

Now I want to consolidate all brand which have same name, give `owl:sameAs` inference to it, and insert in into rule set --

```
rdfs_rule_set('samebrands', 'samebrands');
```

However, when I add more inference, Virtuoso told me I can't add more than 1 inference to query.

How should I do it? Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use another pragma:

```
DEFINE input:same-as "yes"
```

[See the documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrule.html).

Another approach is to define an inference rule which contains two graphs (GR and samebrands).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a separate ontology that includes the terms that you want to use for inference. If it is all terms from another ontology then use `owl:imports`